# sheets giving importrange internal error but loads data on formula refresh

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

we have several sheets that rely on `importrange` to get data from other google sheets, beginning this week we have had trouble getting some of them to load, we just get #ref import range internal error.

I have tried a wide variety of solutions but all of them seem to only work temporarily whereupon refreshing the query it will sometimes manage to get the data, the size of the range is not the problem since the problem happens in large imports as well as imports that only get 1 cell.

so far the best solution I have is deleting the **`=`** from the formula and then adding it back to force the data to load again however this only lasts for around 30 min before the `importrange` goes back to giving the same error.

the formulas aren't anything fancy

```
=IMPORTRANGE("sheet url","Update_Guide!b2:n2")
```

I have tried variations of capital letters for the ranges, as well as adding if error to try and load a variation of the formula

```
=iferror(IMPORTRANGE("sheet url","Update_Guide!b2:n2"),
         IMPORTRANGE("sheet url","Update_Guide!B2:N2"))
```

but nothing seems to work, or when it works the solution doesn't seem to stick.

any help or insight into what may be causing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

`IMPORTRANGE` has a limitation of 50 formulas per spreadsheet if you are using the old version of Google Sheets. if that's not the case you may have broken spreadsheet (it happens). in either case, try to create a fresh new spreadsheet and add your formulas there...

**https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create**

Answer (score -1):

The suggestion by player0 to delete the = sign and type it back in is a good suggestion. Though it did not work for me, it gave me the idea to delete "range" from "importrange" - hit enter - delete what was added and retype "range" into "importrange" Work perfectly. All my cells in the chart returned.

Thanks for the tip.